# Looking for a entry-level carbon 29" hardtail in US - where to buy?

Tags: carbon, shopping, 29er

looking for a new bike and decided that 29" hardtail with good carbon frame is the way to go. I am looking at $2000-3000 budget, and it seems that I can find something within this range if I look at lower spec'd models.

Specifically, it seems that BMC Twostroke 01 three, four, or five (https://www.bmc-switzerland.com/us_en/models/mountain/twostroke.html) will put me in this range.

But now I am facing an availability problem. None of the stores in my area (Seattle) have the bikes in my size or can order them. BMC website is also not helpful.

Where do people buy bikes online these days? Maybe someone would recommend other bike models that would fit the criteria and be easier to procure?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a shopping question, which would be off topic.     Personally I'd not spend money on a bike sight-unseen, unless there was a rock solid return policy.

Comment: Voted to close as off topic.  However, the answer to this part of the question: "Where do people buy bikes online these days?", is that you don't.  You either browse daily hoping for some new stock, or you place an order with a bike shop and keep fingers crossed it doesn't take until 2023 to arrive

Comment: This question will likely be closed.  I'd check around the LBS in your area to find one that will accept your order on a future delivery, look for a used one advertised locally, or try one of the many internet only bike companies like Canyon, OBED, etc.  It's a tight market at this point so you will need to be persistent.

Comment: This question is off-topic, but I will mention that there is a global bike shortage right now. Finding bikes and bike parts is a problem for everyone.